# Python multiprocessing error 'ForkAwareLocal' object has no attribute 'connection'

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Below is my code , for which i am facing a multiprocessing issue. I see this question has been asked before and i have tried those solutions but it does not seem to work. Can someone help me out here ?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager


Class X:
    def _init_():


    def method1(number1,var_a, var_b, var_c, var_d):

    return values 

if __name__ == 'main':


    for value in ["X", "Y"]:
        dict_values = Manager().dict()
        with Pool(1) as p:
            p.starmap(method1,
                      [
                          (1, dict_values, var_a, var_b, var_c, var_d),
                          (2, dict_values, var_a, var_b, var_c, var_d),
                          (3, var_a, var_b, var_c, var_d)
                      ])
```

The error i face

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 749, in _callmethod
    conn = self._tls.connection
AttributeError: 'ForkAwareLocal' object has no attribute 'connection'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 47, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 753, in _callmethod
    self._connect()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 740, in _connect
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 487, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 614, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you were using Pycharm with Run with Python console option checked in Run/Debug Configuration.
Try uncheck that.

Comment: :-O I would never have guessed this. Even now I know that's what was causing my problem, I can't find any other reference to it by searching online. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of this problem is the main thread is done so crash the connection between two processes. However, the subprocess is still running and it needs to throw stuff out via the queue. So keep the main thread alive is our solution.

https://jaime-lin.medium.com/python-multiprocessing-manager-error-forkawarelocal-object-has-no-attribute-496009c94aed

Comment: This was the cause for me too, thanks.  The `process.join()` wasn't getting called.